# Error when reading text file with fscanf()

Tags: c, file, fopen, clion, c11

I am trying to read from a text file using `fscanf()` and I am getting the output:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The crash happens the first time `fscanf()` is called. here is my code:

```
int i=0;

FILE * trafficFile;
trafficFile = fopen("../trafficCount.txt","r");
if (trafficFile == NULL){
    printf("Could not open traffic file\n");
}

int n = 30;
fscanf(trafficFile,"%d",n);
printf("%d",n);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    fscanf(trafficFile, "%d %d", temp, temp2);
    printf("%d %d\n", temp, temp2);
}
fclose(trafficFile);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should have got compiler warnings, and you should not have ignored them.

Comment: To be fair, the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) isn't very clear about the *receiving arguments* in the description text. But understanding [basic examples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Example) should be the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the address of the integer variables to `fscanf()`

```
fscanf(trafficFile, "%d", &n);

fscanf(trafficFile, "%d %d", &temp, &temp2);
```